# Angular 8 - Reactive form: Select male option from dropdown and return me null

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

https://imgur.com/a/JqIdl15
picture console log

I believe I did everything right but I do not understand why the option returns me NULL I choose a man or a woman and it returns me NULL It could be that I used npm of TextMaskModule IN THE PHONE INPUT? Or could it be because of some material I added that it destroys the action?

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Multi Step Form | CodingNepal</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <header>Signup Form</header>
         <!-- form start -->
         <form id="Login" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="signupForm" >
         <mat-horizontal-stepper [labelPosition]="'bottom'">
           
            <mat-step errorMessage="Error!" [stepControl]="signupForm" label="Name" >
                  <!---maybe we can just change the font to red and the icon this is one option-->
                    <!-- <ng-template matStepLabel>
                        <p>Name</p>
                    </ng-template> -->
                    <div>
                        
                            <div class="title">Basic Info:</div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="label">First Name <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
                                <input formControlName="firstName" type="text" >
                                  <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.firstName!.valid && (signupForm.controls.firstName!.dirty || signupForm.controls.firstName?.touched)" 
                                    style="color: red"> It must contain at least One lowercase | uppercase alphabetical character
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="label">Last Name <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
                                <input formControlName="lastName" type="text"  >
                                  <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.lastName!.valid && (signupForm.controls.lastName!.dirty || signupForm.controls.lastName?.touched)" 
                                      style="color: red"> It must contain at least One lowercase | uppercase alphabetical character
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <button class="firstNext next" matStepperNext>Next</button>                    
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            </mat-step>
            
            <mat-step state="iconContact" errorMessage="Error!" [stepControl]="signupForm" label="Contact Info:">
                <div class="title">Contact Info:</div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label">Email Address <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
              <input formControlName="email" type="email">
                <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.email!.valid && (signupForm.controls.email!.dirty || signupForm.controls.email?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red"> Invalid email
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label" >Phone Number <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
              <input id="phone" formControlName="phone" type="text" [textMask]="{mask:mask}" placeholder="_ _ _-_ _ _-_ _ _ _" >
                <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.phone!.valid && (signupForm.controls.phone!.dirty || signupForm.controls.phone?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red"> Invalid phone 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label">Address <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
              <input formControlName="address" type="text" >
                <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.address!.valid && (signupForm.controls.address!.dirty || signupForm.controls.address?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red"> Address is required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label">City <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
              <input formControlName="city" type="text" >
                <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.city!.valid && (signupForm.controls.city!.dirty || signupForm.controls.city?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red"> City is required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label">Country <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
              <input formControlName="country" type="text" >
                <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.country!.valid && (signupForm.controls.country!.dirty || signupForm.controls.country?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red"> country is required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field btns"> <br>
              <button class="prev-1 prev" matStepperPrevious>Previous</button>
              <button class="next-1 next" matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
            
            </mat-step>

            <mat-step state="iconBirth" label="Birth" errorMessage="Error!" [stepControl]="signupForm">
                <div class="title">Date of Birth:</div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label">Date</div>
              <input formControlName="date" type="date" >
                <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.date!.valid && (signupForm.controls.date!.dirty || signupForm.controls.date?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red"> Date is required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label">Gender <span style="color: red;">*</span></div> <br>
              <select formControlName="gender"> 
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
              <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.gender!.valid && (signupForm.controls.gender!.dirty || signupForm.controls.gender?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red"> Date is required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field btns"> <br> <br> <br><br>
              <button class="prev-1 prev" matStepperPrevious>Previous</button>
              <button class="next-1 next" matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
            </mat-step>

            <mat-step state="iconSubmit" label="Submit">
                <div class="title">Login Details:</div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label">Username <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
              <input formControlName="userName" type="text">
                <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.userName!.valid && (signupForm.controls.userName!.dirty || signupForm.controls.userName?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red"> Invalid is required
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="label">Password <span style="color: red;">*</span></div>
              <input formControlName="password" type="password" >
              <div *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.password!.valid && (signupForm.controls.password!.dirty || signupForm.controls.password?.touched)" 
                    style="color: red">
                    <li>It must not contain any whitespace.</li> <br>
                    <li>It must contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase and one numeric character.</li> <br>
                    <li>It must contain at least one special character. [!@#$]</li> 
           
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field btns"> <br>
              <button class="prev-1 prev" matStepperPrevious>Previous</button>
              <button type="submit" class="next-1 next" [disabled]="!signupForm.valid" matStepperNext>Submit</button>
            </div>
            </mat-step>
        

          <!-- Change Icons-->
        <ng-template matStepperIcon="iconContact">
            <i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template matStepperIcon="iconBirth">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template matStepperIcon="iconSubmit">
            <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
        </ng-template>
        </mat-horizontal-stepper>
      </form>
      <!-- form end -->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css'],
    providers:[
      {
        provide:STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS,
        useValue: {
          showError:true,
          displayDefaultIndicatorType: false
        }
      }
    ]
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  signupForm: FormGroup;
  completed = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createLoginForm();
  }
  createLoginForm(){
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('',[Validators.required , Validators.pattern('^[A-Z|a-z| ]+$')]),
      lastName: new FormControl('',[Validators.required , Validators.pattern('^[A-Z|a-z| ]+$')]),
      email: new FormControl('',[Validators.required , Validators.email]),
      phone: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      date: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      address: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Z|a-z| |0-9]+$')]),
      userName: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      password: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      gender: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
      city: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Z|a-z| ]+$')]),
      country: new FormControl('',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Z|a-z| ]+$')]),
    })
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.signupForm.value); 
  }

  public mask= [/[0-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];

}
```

Comment: Does the validation works for the gender? if appears that it is required?

Answer (score 0):

I got it running on this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-drrgsu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsignup.component.html

though is super ugly since there is no styling. Gender is printed in the console as expected. Only change I made was to remove the mask to run, because I didn't install that dependency.